How can I extend a toilet valve to clear the tank?
My toilet stopped working so I had to get a new one and I couldn't just go for a standard toilet. No, I had to get the one with a skirt because "it's easier to clean". Anyway, the piping situation and the fact that everything is enclosed doesn't leave much room to move about to begin with.
This valve, and the lack of space makes it impossible to hook the line to it. What is the best way to extend and make this piece a little longer so it misses the tank? I was thinking a 3/4 m to f adapter or is there a longer version of what I already had which is 3/4 male to female and 1/4 male 3 way compression fitting?





I"m thinking a flexible line is what you're looking for, but have no way of knowing for sure. Any chance that you can add some pictures so we can see what you're seeing?

Thank you, I forgot to add the pictures! So as you can see it is a tight squeeze to get to the toilet tank. The flexible supply line will connect to the 3 way valve and that is what I need to get up into the tank.  the side connector is inline with the toilet, so the only way I can even try is to have it face the toilet and it is just impossible to get it connected.

With a toilet that stop working, most people either replace parts not working or clean out the drain line with a plunger/snake.  Getting a new toilet is saved for redoing the bathroom or the toilet cracks/breaks into pieces.

If you’re trying to extend the copper at the wall, you can remove the short stub with a sharkbite removal tool and put in a longer stub. But that just makes things more awkward. Just get a longer braided supply line.

Ok, I'll state the obvious.  The flex supply line should have been attached to the shutoff before the toilet was installed.  If it is impossible to get attached now, remove the toilet and attach the line , then reinstall the toilet.  Now I also ask, is this fancy toilet really worth it?

@RMDman might be worth shortening the pipe a tad too, while OP has the toilet out—looks like the toilet bottoms out against the valve handle.

I'm not clear on the problem here. Is it that things don't fit, or that you can't access them? I tightened up your post a bit (it's not evening here, now). Maybe you can revise further to be very specific on what's conflicting.
